# Creating superuser in django-nonrel

Tags: google-app-engine, django-nonrel

I'm a newbie been going through the django-nonrel tutorials and have set up django-nonrel inside of Google App Engine.

I am now trying to create a superuser using:

> manage.py createsuperuser --username=joe --email=joe@example.com

I get

> Unknown command: 'createsuperuser'
> Type 'manage.py help' for usage

When I type manage.py help, I don't see createsuperuser listed.

Help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solved this. For anyone else having the same problem, in order to get admin to work:

1) Ensure that *django.contrib.auth* is installed_apps section in your settings.py

2) Stop runserver, then createsuperuser using *manage.py createsuperuser*. 
AFTER you've created the superuser, start runserver again.

Comment: Nice, forgot to stop the server. Guess more people forget that easily

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I'm on GoogleAppEngine 1.6.2 with python 2.7.2.

Comment: If this is a new django install, then don't forget to run `python manage.py syncdb` first.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still not able to create superuser, you can try it from appengine admin web interface. When you start your application you can see similar log:

```
prost@prost-VirtualBox:~/projects/website$ ./manage.py runserver
WARNING:root:The rdbms API is not available because the MySQLdb library could not be loaded.
INFO:google.appengine.tools.appengine_rpc:Server: appengine.google.com
INFO:root:Checking for updates to the SDK.
INFO:root:Running application dev~incloudscz on port 8000: http://127.0.0.1:8000
INFO:root:Admin console is available at: http://127.0.0.1:8000/_ah/admin
...
...
```

The last line with admin console is URL of an admin interface. You can create/view user there via "Datastore viewer" -> "Entity kind: auth_user" -> "List entities" or "Create entity" with is_superuser set to True.

Answer (score 0):

Behind the scenes, Django maintains a list of “[authentication backends](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#authentication-backends)” that it checks for authentication. As a result of this there could be a few additional problems you can run into. So in addition to @iali's answer. You need to make sure that you.

1. make sure that your `settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` does not include any additional authentication middleware.
2. make sure that your `settings.AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` is not set.