# cron.yaml, dae-nonrel, gae

Tags: google-app-engine, scheduling

I managed to get my django project running on gae using djangoappengine-nonrel.  It is able to use sqlite3 which was my db in django project to start with.

Now I am trying to do a background schedule script which some one suggested to use cron.yaml but it seems my cron entry and app.yaml handler entry are not being scheduled.

any one using gae cron.yaml + app.yaml for scheduling and dae-nonrel for running django project ?

Regards,

Miten.

Answer (score 0):

Cron jobs don't run automatically on the dev_appserver, you'll have to hook up cron manually.  But if it's visible in the dev_appserver admin interface, they should launch ok in production.

Remember there's also a separate "appcfg.py update_cron" to deploy the cron jobs as well.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron#Cron_Support_in_the_Development_Server

Comment: I am not sure about url to lauch dev_appserver admin interface.  I have been running the django app using django-appengine setup using python manage.py runserver.  Using the [article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352846/creating-superuser-in-django-nonrel/10026859#10026859) I can logon to django admin interface but not gae admin interface.  I believe you meant by hook up that once I have cron.yaml and a corresponding url handler setup in app.yaml I should be able to force run the cron job in dev server too ?

Comment: It seems no matter what only urls served are the urls.py from django and none from app.yaml.  http://localhost:8000/_ah/admin/cron does not resolve.

Comment: does localhost:8000/_ah/admin work?  Yes, I meant that once cron.yaml is properly set up with a url handler, accessing the url on your local server should kick off your cron job, but it still won't run automatically on schedule.  I might be able to help you if you posted your app.yaml and cron.yaml, but otherwise, I don't know what's broken for you.  I have cron jobs running on django-nonrel ok, both locally on my dev_appserver (manually), and on the actual gae servers.